# git undo merge in remote

Tags: git, git-merge

Merged master into my branch, didnt check the result of merge. After this pushed my branch. 10 mins pass I decided to check the state of my branch and found some mistakes of merging. Now I need to somehow undo that merge or just get the state of my branch as it was before merging.

Havent done any commits after merge, only pushed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-merge%5D+undo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article that explains how to undo a merge:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-undo-merge-how-to-revert-the-last-merge-commit-in-git/